# Android using viewmodel to store fragment UI state

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that uses android jetpack's new features like nav graph and viewmodel. My app has a bottom navigation bar with 3 tabs(Profile, Journal, Workouts) , each tab loads a difference fragment. The purpose of Workouts fragment is the user picks an exercise and then presses a button to directly open journal fragment and adds it automatically to a listview in journal.

The problem I'm facing is, I need the list that was created to be saved to always be visible to the user even when switching fragments. Atleast until the app is closed. Right now when I switch to workout fragment and then back to journal, the list that was created in journal is gone. So journal is just getting recreated and destroyed, but I don't want it destroyed unless the app closes. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please put your code in question. so I will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences or sqlite DB for storing data locally.